# Windows Update Fails Error Code 80072f78

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have tried reseting the winsock

```
netsh winsock reset
```

and tcp/ip

```
netsh int ip reset
```

But I still get this error.. I even cleared the win7 update Directory

```
C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution
```

I need to update to Windows 7 ServicePack1 to run Adobe CS5

The size of SP1 in windows update utility is smaller than the one available on the microsoft's download center.

Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Win 7 SP1 Windows Update offers is a "Stub installer", it will download the rest of hte service pack as it installs, whereas the one in the Download Center is (probably) the complete SP1 image.

Download [the full version](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c3202ce6-4056-4059-8a1b-3a9b77cdfdda) and try it.

Microsoft has a page devoted to Windows 7 SP1 install problems: http://windows.microsoft.com/troubleshootwindows7sp1

[Here's some advice](http://www.pagestart.com/win7sp1steps021611.html) on things to try to increase the chances of SP1 installing properly.

Blurb:

> 1. Check your available disk space - For now the best information available is as follows:
> 2. Run Disk Cleanup.
> 3. Create a new System Restore point just prior to installing SP1.
> 4. If at all possible create an Image Backup of the Windows drive or partition.
> 5. Install the Windows 7 device drivers for your make and model of computer, graphics adapter and other add-in cards.
> 6. Disable AV Software.
> 7. Run the `SFC /SCANNOW` command.
> 8. Run the [System Update Readiness Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821/en-us).
> 9. Rename the 'Software Distribution folder'
> 10. Check your Power Plan configuration.
> 11. Perform a [“Clean Boot”](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135) to prevent other programs for interfering with the installation process.
> 12. Laptop users should connect their computer to AC power.

Lastly, MS provides free support for installation problems with SP1.  Check out your support options with MS, [here](https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?&gprid=14496&&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn).

Answer (score 3):

The error code `80072F78` signals a certificate that is either expired or "from the future".

To solve this problem, you have to make sure that your time and date are properly set.